# htaccess redirect to exclude certain pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, duplicates

My htaccess file currently redirects everything and has this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

I need to exclude two urls that begin with "send"

I changed the last line to

```
RewriteRule !^send(.*)  https://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

It excluded the send urls but any url in a subfolder is redirected to the root index page.

Comment: Why are you only redirecting port 80 (HTTP)? What if you get a request to `/send...` on HTTPS?

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: No more directives.  The request for send... only come from http. It's a volley request from an android app. Didn't work after redirected to https but works fine now. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule !^send(.*)  https://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
> ```

Negated patterns don't capture anything (by definition), but trying to capture everything after `send` when `send` is not present in the URL, doesn't make much sense.

You can do something like the following and use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable in the *substitution* instead of the backreference:

```
RewriteRule !^send https://www.domain.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Note that the `REQUEST_URI` server variable already contains the slash prefix.